# Javascript: is leveraging a local reference to yourself acceptable coding practice?

Tags: javascript, callback, this

As I've starting working with Javascript, I learned the hard way that when you pass an external event handler (like a timer) a reference to a function in your object, you can't rely on `this.` to refer to your object - it will instead refer to the scope of whatever fired the event (in the case of the timer, I think it's `window`?).

The work around I saw being used is to create a private / local reference to yourself and use that within the callback logic.  For example:

```
function MyObject() { 
  var myThis = this;
  this.foo = true; 
  this.callback = function() { return myThis.foo; }
  this.interval = 30;
  setInterval(function () { myThis.callback(); }, myThis.interval);
}
```

Is this standard coding practice for situations like this, if not, what is the preferred alternative and why (eg. what are the risks of the above example)?

Comment: Both solid answers - thanks guys :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A modern alternative would be to use `Function.prototype.bind()`...

```
setInterval(this.callback.bind(this), this.interval);
```

The `.bind()` method returns a function with the `this` value bound to first argument you provided *(which in this case is the enclosing `this` value)*.

It avoids the need to reference the desired `this` value in a variable of the enclosing variable scope from within the variable scope of a nested function (as shown in your question), providing cleaner code.

---

You can find a compatibility patch that is sufficient for most cases [at `MDN`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) for older implementations.

---

Side note, the question of the value of `this` in JavaScript is not a scope question, but rather  a calling context question.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: This is an accepted practice, and there aren't any drawbacks as far as I know.

Long(ish) answer: you can manipulate the Prototype method to do this, see **am not i am**'s answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using an interim "this" and without using bind by using closures.

*This is not the supposed to be a good way to do this in practice*, but it rather is illustrative of how closures and binding contexts work. If you can understand why this works, then you should be able to see how you could code `function.prototype.bind` to do the same thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/WRJqF/

```
function MyObject() { 
    this.foo = true; 
    this.callback = function() { 
        // firebug
        console.log( this.foo); 
    };
    this.interval = 30;

    setTimeout((function (that) {
        return function() {
            that.callback();
       };
   }(this)), this.interval); 

}
```

This uses two javascript concepts you'll use a lot.

1 - Self-executing function. By wrapping a function in parenthesis, it runs immediately, and is effectively replaced inline with its return value, e.g.

```
(function add(x,y) {
    return x+y;
}(2,3))
```

becomes `6`.

In the example above we used a self-executing function and passed `this` as the parameter. This creates a closure and the value of the parameter (named `that` just to confuse you) is permanently associated with that function.

2 - functions as first class objects. Since you can return a function (or generally use them like any other value), you can return a function from your self-executing function, which is bound with the value of `this` from the stack frame that created it. So the self-executing function is, effectively,

```
function() {
    that.callback();
};
```

... but "that" is in fact the "this" that was effective when the function was created!

Got all that??

Comment: ... all except for that third concept you mentioned :P

Comment: I removed it.. sorry. It didn't really make sense in this situation. But look up `call` and `apply` because they are used to assign an arbitrary `this` context to anything. Very useful and closely related to bind.

Comment: While this works, OP's original code also takes advantage of closures by defining the local `myThis` variable and referencing it in the anonymous function. I thought the best part of your answer was using `.call()` in place of OP's original `myThis.callback()`, but you removed that part! :P

Comment: I *prefer* op's method - and I think it is the correct solution in practice. I was trying to add to this discussion by demonstrating how closures work more explicitly by using an inline function instead of using the whole object as a closure. I definitely remember this being hard to get my head around when I was learning it. The code with `call` didn't acually work :) because I don't have a reference to `callback` only to `that`! So you could pass callback too but since it's a property of `this` didn't seem to make sense.

Comment: But since you have a reference to `that`, you have a reference to `callback`. I only saw the original code briefly, so I don't remember exactly how it was, but you should be able to do `that.callback.call(that)`. Anyway +1 for a valid alternative using an IIFE.

Comment: That's what I mean.. `that.callback.call(that)` is redundant. `that.callback()` explicitly assigns `that` as the context.

Comment: ...oh wait, yeah, no need for `.call()` since you've established the calling context with `that.callback()`. Doh!

Comment: Yeah, I wanted it to be that way, but it just wasn't, and it was too late to rewrite the example :)